# Checking which date comes first?

Tags: java, android

It seems logical that there should be some simple method to check which `DatePicker` object comes first but I can't find done.

```
// so if you had two objects
final DatePicker start_datepicker = (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.DatePickerStart);
final DatePicker end_datepicker = (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.DatePickerEnd);

// I was thinking something along the lines of:
if (end_datepicker > start_datepicker) {
  // something
}

// or is there something like 
if (end_datepicker.isLarger(start_datepicker)) {
  // Something
}
```

Is this possible or does anyone know of something simple along these lines to compare to dates?

Comment: Please edit your post to correctly format your 'java'-code. Improving codequality will help others to help you solving the problem and is one of the main guidelines of stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A DatePicker is a UI widget for displaying a date. You don't set it by assignment (as in your code) but by calling it's `init` method. Typically you would then track the date using an OnDateChangedListener. Nevertheless, you can compare the current dates displayed on two such widgets with something like this:

```
/** Returns a number <0, 0, or >0 when dp1 displays a date <, =, or > dp2. */
public int compare(DatePicker dp1, DatePicker dp2) {
    int compare = dp1.getYear() - dp2.getYear();
    if (compare == 0) {
        compare = dp1.getMonth() - dp2.getMonth();
        if (compare == 0) {
            compare = dp1.getDay() - dp2.getDay();
        }
    }
    return compare;
}
```

Comment: yes, I am getting the date dates from a widget but I wondered if there was a better way to compare them. I thought of your solution but it seems there should be an easier way to compare two date objects. The above method should be built in in some way but maybe it is not. I will correct my code above.

Comment: But since this seems to be the best way, I'll do this. Thanks Ted for even writing the code! very nice of you

Answer (score 0):

[`Date`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html) has [`before()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#before%28java.util.Date%29) and [`after()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#after%28java.util.Date%29) methods.. just for that.

Comment: I also tried to see if there is a way to get `Date` but there is none. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html

Comment: seems strange there is no one line solution to compare dates from a widget

Comment: @gurung yea I was sure the datePicker UI can return a Date object (I never got to use it) my mistake. really odd though..

Comment: @Stagleton: Just put this ready to go method somewhere and it will be a one liner. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8436481/738746

Comment: hoping to avoid reinventing the wheel, but if the wheel hasn't been made then I'll use this

Comment: @gurung - Um, didn't you just link to my answer on this same thread?

Comment: @TedHopp: Yes I did because I felt like it's the best he could get.

Answer (score 0):

You should take the resulting values from the date pickers and convert them to Date objects which will then allow you to easily compare the values rather than going the route of writing your own Comparator that relies on the UI component.

Comment: is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Here is a link to an example of how to take the month, day of the month, and year values you get from DatePicker and turn them into a Date object.
http://www.javadb.com/create-a-date-object-using-the-calendar-class

Answer (score 0):

I actually wrote a [Java class specifically to handle this situation for Android](http://isthisonthetest.com/?q=node/6).  Feel free to use it and include it in your app!  It's documented, as well.